Add & Delete a secret into Azure KeyVault using logic app standard
I'm using the logic app standard, I would like to keep the JWT token in Az KeyVault (as a secret). Read it until it expires. Once it expires I will regenerate and add a new version.
I'm using the code below for reading the key vault with managed identity.
    {
  "type": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "uri": "https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/DK-Test?api-version=7.3",
    "method": "GET",
    "authentication": {
      "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
      "audience": "https://vault.azure.net"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {},
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "contentTransfer": {
      "transferMode": "Chunked"
    }
  }
}


Can someone please help me to let me know How to add & delete a secret into Azure KeyVault using logic app standard?
I didn't find a connector so far, Can we do this using an HTTP connector?
Thanks for the reply,
DK

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/update-secret/update-secret?view=rest-keyvault-secrets-7.4&tabs=HTTP

Azure Key Vault Secret Updates using Logic App
https://samanax.com/2021/09/13/azure-key-vault-secret-updates-using-logic-app/
I tried it with a different approach. Using HTTP trigger and it worked






I found the solution after spending some time, here is the code:
Add:
{
  "type": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "uri": "https://xxxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/DK-Test?api-version=7.3",
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": {
      "attributes": {
        "exp": 1788145100
      },
      "value": "abc-logic-app-test"
    },
    "authentication": {
      "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
      "audience": "https://vault.azure.net"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "NewToken": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "contentTransfer": {
      "transferMode": "Chunked"
    }
  }
}

Delete:
{
  "type": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "uri": "https://xxxxxxxxx.azure.net/secrets/Del-Me?api-version=7.3",
    "method": "DELETE",
    "authentication": {
      "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
      "audience": "https://vault.azure.net"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "AddNewToken-Ecase": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "staticResult": {
      "name": "HTTP_10",
      "staticResultOptions": "Enabled"
    },
    "contentTransfer": {
      "transferMode": "Chunked"
    }
  }
}

